# Build SOQL dynamic query in LWC component

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-web-components, query

Is it secure to build SOQL queries on front-end side (lwc component) and pass them to Apex for execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how the query is used. When passing to Apex, make sure you use `inherited sharing` on the class, and `Security.stripInaccessible` to ensure users can't see fields/records they're not supposed to. In addition, make sure the user doesn't have access to any unnecessary fields or objects. As long as your configuration is perfectly secure, constructing a dynamic SOQL is just as secure. After all, a tech-savvy user could just use the console directly to attempt to perform a query by calling the ui-api directly. There's no additional harm that can be done by building a dynamic query if everything is locked down the way it should be.